If I denoise in compositor will it override render settings denoiser?
I am using OptiX and rendering with "denoise" checked under render samples settings and I have few technical questions about it.

Does using denoise pass + having denoise node setup in compositor override that render settings denoising? (If I have it in render settings and in compositor will it pick compositor and ignore the render settings)
Is render settings denoise checkmark a better/worse method (are they different) than compositor denoising using denoise pass?

Render denoise setting I am talking about:

Compositor setup:


As the node has "Image" and "Noisy Image", It's sort of natural to think that the render denoise will be used in "Image" and not in "Noisy Image" and whatever additional nodes you put will act "on top" of your choice.

That makes sense. any difference between denoising noisy image and using render denoiser?

That's for the experts
